# How to subdivide this face?

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface

A sphere was created and then a bool difference modifier applied against a cube. A face was then separated from the sphere but an attempt to add geometry to it failed. The vertex count from stats suggests it has vertices but I can't tell what state it is in and why they can't be seen in the mesh.

The face has no depth but neither does a plane so is the arc of the hypotenuse the problem?

[image]

[image: Sphere face 1]

Update:
[image: Sphere face 2]

Comment: First, you're in face select mode, switch back to vertex view with 1 to see the vertices on the arc

Comment: @AllenSimpson Thanks total noob here. So in vertex mode i see verts, I guess i expected to see more in a grid like overlay rather than just at a,b edges. Im trying to create a series of smaller and smaller arcs i.e. reduced radius within this face and then extrude each arc to different heights with the outer arc being the tallest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess I would move the cursor to the single corner vert

[image]

And then delete that vertex and change your pivot point to 3d Cursor

[image]

And then select the outer edge and Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> + Scale <kbd>S</kbd> all the way down.

[image]

<kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> for the final step, and then you'll probably want to apply some judicious merging of vertices.

But if you keep it to an all-quad topology you can apply subdivision without any problems.  If you wait to merge the corner until the end you can generate quads all the way down.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want the topology to have more or less the same sized and shaped faces with cleaner and mostly quad topology, albeit a bit more manual with a few triangles, you can try this procedure. First remove the faces of the *UV Sphere* in *Edit Mode* so you can see the interior (here in red).

- Press <kbd>1</kbd> to switch to *Vertex Select* mode
- Select the loop of vertices except the 3 vertices on each side (encircled yellow)
- Go to mesh menu *Edge > Bridge Edge Loops*

[image]

- Select the vertices that weren't bridged then press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill faces.
- Select one pair of vertices at a time on opposite ends and press <kbd>J</kbd> to subdivide faces

[image]

- Do the previous step w/ each pair of vertices on opposite ends
- Press <kbd>3</kbd> to switch to *Face Select* mode
- Select the faces that are no longer needed and press Press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Delete Faces*

[image]

- Change *Transform Pivot Point* to *3D Cursor*
- Select the faces of the quartered circle shape
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> then type `90` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Again Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
- Press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> then type `90` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

- Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces
- Press <kbd>M</kbd> *> Merge By Distance* to remove duplicate vertices

[image]

Similarly you could manually arrange vertices to create a pure quad topology:

[image]

Comment: This is also an excellent answer and what i wanted next. Im doing this weird amphitheater, (think hollywood bowl but not really)  kinda thing for fun, so this is very helpful too.

Comment: cool glad it was helpful too! :)